# how can i input a float value with 0 as it last digit into database?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, tags

so, i have a problem that doesn't really sure how to fix it, lets say i have :

```
<input type="number" id="input" name="input" class="form-control" placeholder="insert here" step=".01" required></br>
```

and i have a database to it witch is float. but every time i input with x.x0 the 0 in the end is always disappear.

any thought? thank you

Comment: You need to read up on how data is stored and how to format it for being displayed. Those are 2 different things.

Comment: 1.2 and 1.20 is the same value

Comment: but if i want to add subtraction to it lets say 1.2 - 0.53 i cant get my desired result

Comment: What do you mean, 1.20 - 0.53 and 1.2 - 0.53 is the same equation. Your problem is probably elsewhere-

Answer (score 2):

Changing MySQL column type from float into **Decimal** keeps trailing zeros. [Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9688372a04aaaa985b38a83c6ec5c4bf) I create a test and example.

```
create table trailing_zeros (input_number decimal(15,2))
```

Comment: i change my DB into decimal but its only make it rounding up. like i insert 99.80 and it just turn into 100

Comment: In  `decimal(A,B) ` A is the precision and B is the scale. If you have 100.40 number you should set decimal(5,2) 
After that, I thought data saved with ".00" but we have a problem in displaying. You can use `CONCAT`    Example:
 `SELECT CONCAT(input_number) from trailing_zeros; `

Answer (score 0):

You can put 2 after the length of your field like FLOAT(15,2) for 2 digit after .

```
ALTER TABLE tablename MODIFY columnname FLOAT(15,2) ;
```

Comment: It should be does, if the problem was in storing into database.

Comment: In your link doesn't work because you're forget to put 2 after comma, try to change f2 Float(6,2)

Comment: My answer is almost same with the other one, so why you don't comment on the other answer

Comment: You are right, I thought Float(x,y) was very different from Decimal(x,y) but it isn't. The only issue with your answer then is that Float(x,y) is non-standard sql and has been deprecated from 8.0.17. But I will remove the down vote